# How to wait until ng2 will complete changing the DOM

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a print functionality in my web-app. I am using jquery print plugin to display in print-preview only few elements in dom. I want to make sure that I start printing only when all data have been rendered.
In current implementation - sometimes print preview appears with not all information in dom(I think ng2 uses some kind of deferred operations).

Take a look at the sample:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyCoolComponent{|

myModel:MyModel;


print(){
   _myService.fetchDataSomehow().subscribe((newData:MyModel)=>{
       this.myModel = newData;
       // I need to wait until ng2 will adjust dom with new data in synchronous manner
       $(this._el).print();
   })
}
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
  {{myModel.field1}}
  {{myModel.field2}}
  {{myModel.field3}}
  //...and a lot of other fields from myModel
</div>
```

I know that I can use `setTimeout(()=>{...}, 1)`, but it looks silly. Is there more solid approach to wait until angular 2 adjusted dom due to model changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkout ngAfterViewChecked in the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), maybe it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I have tried that to use ngAfterViewChecked, but it fire multiple times for each change in DOM. But I need to track somehow when the last changes have been applied to DOM.

Comment: do you know how many element will make a change? if so you could add counter that would increment with every ngAfterViewChecked. If counter reaches the limit everything would be settled.

Comment: @kit what if I want to do something after every view checked? This is challenging because everything will trigger a change detection cycle so I wind up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be just to add `*ngIf` to your html.

If you want to render nothing until there is a value in `myModel`, do something like.

```
<div *ngIf="myModel">
  {{myModel.field1}}
  {{myModel.field2}}
  {{myModel.field3}}
</div>
```

This will check to see if there is any value to `myModel`. If it does, then it will render.

You can also add "loading text" as you are fetching by checking if `myModel` has no value and handling it appropriately

```
<div *ngIf="!myModel">
     Fetching Data...
</div>
```

Comment: There is a data at the moment when I try to print page. But it is not yet rendered/partially rendered, so I am not sure how ngIf will help in that case.